# How to find pattern with brain.js

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, lstm, brain.js

**Disclaimer:** *I am new to machine learning. Please forgive me if I am asking a super dumb question.*

Hi I am trying to find pattern in a set of numbers using brain.js.

I have expanded on the example in brain.js github page.

```
const net = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimeStep({
  inputSize: 3,
  hiddenLayers: [10],
  outputSize: 3
});

net.train([
  [1, 1, 1],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [3, 3, 3],
  [4, 4, 4],
  [5, 5, 5],
  [6, 6, 6],
  [7, 7, 7],
  [8, 8, 8]
]);

const output = net.run([[7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]]);
```

I was trying to get an output of [9, 9, 9], but I am mostly getting [8, 8, 8].

But if I try running `const output = net.run([[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]);` I am easily getting [7, 7, 7] & consecutive output with other numbers in the training data sequence.

Is there anyway to train it so that I can get the desired output and the use it for other patters?

Comment: You should convert your numbers to be between 0 and 1. Secondly a simple neural network will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a LSTM time step recurrent neural network trained using "supervised learning": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning, which provides similar output values it has been given previously to the `.run()` call.

What it seems you want is a LSTM time step recurrent neural network trained using "reinforcement learning": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning, which can output values it has seen before, but also new ones, using values it has never been given previously to the `.run()` call, based off exploitation and exploratory (random) findings.

Brain.js doesn't yet have a reinforcement learning API, although that will be the focus after v2 stabilizes.

Ty for providing a clear question and reproduction steps.  I've included your sample, working in the browser so others can play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/robertleeplummerjr/4o2vcajt/1/

Comment: Hi @robert-plummer any news on the reinforcement learning?